# What is the benefit of SequenceEqual?

Tags: c#, performance, linq, ienumerable

I did a comparison between SequenceEqual and element comparison in for loop.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //var myList = new List<short>();
        //var anotherList = new List<short>();
        var myList = new short[2000000];
        var anotherList = new short[2000000];

        for (int i = 0; i < 2000000; i++)
        {
            //myList.Add(5);
            //anotherList.Add(5);
            myList[i] = 5;
            anotherList[i] = 5;
        }

        var watch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
        //for (int i = 0; i < 2000000; i++)
        //{
        //    if (myList[i] != anotherList[i])
        //        break;
        //}
        bool isEqual = myList.SequenceEqual(anotherList);
        watch.Stop();
        var elapsedMs = watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
        Console.WriteLine(elapsedMs);
        Console.Read();
    }
```

In the case when myList and anotherList are arrays, the direct comparison executes for 4 ms, SequenceEqual executes for 21ms. When myList and anotherList are lists, the direct comparison executes for 13 ms, SequenceEqual for 30 ms.

If it is so much slower, are there cases when it would be beneficial to use? I can only think of one, that it saves several lines of code.

Comment: It uses the default equality comparer for the type which is not necessarily the same thing you get with ==

Comment: @Crowcoder I can try with Equals but I doubt there would be much difference.

Comment: Well if you compare arrays with 2 million items each (which are happened to also be equal, which is the worst case), in a perfomance critical application - then sure you should not use `SequenceEquals`. But in most other real-life applications difference in perfomance between them doesn't matter, while "saves several lines" is.

Comment: @Evk You have a point. What makes me wonder is why it is not optimized to provide the maximum possible performance. Perhaps because it is extension method of an interface which doesn't know for its implementations, but it could have at least checked for the most common cases (lists and arrays) like Count checks for ICollection.

Comment: I agree, it could have checked for that. Maybe even worth adding issue on their github about that.

Comment: @Evk On a second thought though, if it checks, then it should cast afterwards...

Comment: The other one is when you are not using `SequenceEqual` with `ICollection` but full generic `IEnumerable`. Are two large files equal? You could do `File.ReadLines(f1).SequenceEqual(File.ReadLines(f2))` without using much memory. Also, you don't want to `Count` a generic `IEnumerable` so you can't know the lengths are the same as in your tests.

Comment: But it will be identity cast (I mean something like 'source as T[]'), so should be fast, since no conversion of anything is performed.

Comment: No one has mentioned that your contrived example loop is able to safely make an assumption (that both arrays have 2 million elements) that `SequenceEqual()` can't make.

Comment: Also, I don't think your direct comparison returns a boolean?

Comment: @NetMage I doubt this boolean impacts performance significantly.

Comment: @itsme86 SequenceEqual() also uses a loop internally.

Comment: @MBakardzhiev I don't see the relevance. My point is that the contrived example loop isn't checking that both arrays still have values to to compare. You're able to just blindly assume that they're equal lengths since you have previous knowledge of the arrays. Adding a check `if (i < myList.Length && i < anotherList.Length)` would be more representative.

Comment: @itsme86 True, it is an optimization which SequenceEqual() doesn't do (and I think it should when it can).

Comment: I did more testing. The a big part of the slow down appears to be in `SequenceEqual` treating the `List`s as `IEnumerable` and having to use the generic `Enumerator`. Using the `List` specific `Enumerator` can double the speed.

Comment: @NetMage If you use the enumerator of an array, then I guess the execution would be even faster, perhaps twice as fast as list.

Comment: @MBakardzhiev There isn't a faster enumerator of array for non-objects than the one `SequenceEqual` uses, because there is only the object based `Array.GetEnumerator` that requires box/unbox of the values which is very slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking into especially `List`s more specifically, it seems a lot of slow down comes from the generic implementation in `SequenceEqual` using the generic `IEnumerator` instead of the `List` specific version, which is more than twice as fast. However, if you are going to test for `List` anyway, might as well code in the `for` loop directly instead of using enumeration.

Note that testing for `IList` is a lot slower, because `List` doesn't implement `IList<T>.operator[]` which means it calls `IList.operator[]` which returns `object` and causes boxing.

I also special case `Array`s as the `IList` interface is much slower than direct access, again due to boxing.

Of course, taking advantage of the high speed `Count` or `Length` available for known types makes unequal length comparisons tremendously faster than `SequenceEqual`. OTOH, if the first two elements are unequal, `SequenceEqual` can be faster than my function.

Here is my `LocalSequenceEqual`:

```
public static bool LocalSequenceEqual<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> first, IEnumerable<TSource> second, IEqualityComparer<TSource> comparer = null) {
    if (first is ICollection<TSource> fc && second is ICollection<TSource> sc)
        if (fc.Count != sc.Count)
            return false;

    var cmp = comparer ?? EqualityComparer<TSource>.Default;

    if (first is TSource[] fa && second is TSource[] sa) {
        for (int j1 = 0; j1 < fa.Length; ++j1)
            if (!cmp.Equals(fa[j1], sa[j1]))
                return false;
        return true;
    }

    if (first is List<TSource> fl && second is List<TSource> sl) {
        for (int j1 = 0; j1 < fl.Count; ++j1) {
            if (!cmp.Equals(fl[j1], sl[j1]))
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    using (var e1 = first.GetEnumerator()) {
        using (var e2 = second.GetEnumerator()) {
            while (e1.MoveNext()) {
                if (!(e2.MoveNext() && cmp.Equals(e1.Current, e2.Current)))
                    return false;
            }
            if (e2.MoveNext())
                return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: This is the implementation that I had in mind, thanks for the effort. There are several other types that could benefit from direct casting (SortedList, OrderedDictionary) but they are less common so perhaps it is not worth it.

Comment: @MBakardzhiev At some point the overhead exceeds the worth for the quick unequal cases, and the generic `SortedList<TKey, TValue>` and `OrderedDictionary<TKey, TValue>` don't have optimized special cases that I see.