# Two huge List<string> data should be compared using C# and must ensure performance improves

Tags: c#, performance, comparison, query-optimization

I have two `List<string>` that contain huge data, and I have the following code which I used till now. But I have some doubts regarding this, due to lot of confusion about the data is compared or not in the list items. Here I am using sequence `Equal` to compare the data. I have two questions. Somewhere I found that `SequenceEqual` will compare the data in the lists. So used it.

1. Will `SequenceEqual` compares the data in the lists?
2. Better way of code to improve performance. As per understanding I kept only three items in both the lists but our requirement has huge data items in the lists. So need to improve performance.

   ```
   bool value = false;
   List<string> list1 = new List<string>();
   list1.Add("one");
   list1.Add("two");
   list1.Add("three");

   List<string> list2 = new List<string>();
   list2.Add("one");
   list2.Add("two");
   list2.Add("three");
   list1.Sort();
   list2.Sort();
   if (list1.SequenceEqual(list2))
   {
       value = true;
   }
   else
   {
       value = false;
   }
   return value;
   ```

Comment: Can the lists have *duplicates*, e.g. `{ "one", "two", "three", "one" };` - `"one"` is duplicate?

Comment: please have a look at this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49581893/what-is-the-benefit-of-sequenceequal

Comment: if you want to know if `sequenceequal` is fast enough, you just have to test / benchmark it it. If you know the data and structure it is maybe better to implement your own algorithm.

Comment: Related: [Comparing two collections for equality irrespective of the order of items in them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50098/comparing-two-collections-for-equality-irrespective-of-the-order-of-items-in-the).

Answer (score 1):

Here is the implementation of `SequenceEqual`:

```
public static bool SequenceEqual<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource> first, IEnumerable<TSource> second, IEqualityComparer<TSource> comparer)
{
    if (comparer == null)
    {
        comparer = EqualityComparer<TSource>.Default;
    }
    if (first == null)
    {
        throw Error.ArgumentNull("first");
    }
    if (second == null)
    {
        throw Error.ArgumentNull("second");
    }
    using (IEnumerator<TSource> enumerator = first.GetEnumerator())
    {
        using (IEnumerator<TSource> enumerator2 = second.GetEnumerator())
        {
            while (enumerator.MoveNext())
            {
                if (!enumerator2.MoveNext() || !comparer.Equals(enumerator.Current, enumerator2.Current))
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            if (enumerator2.MoveNext())
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

It does not check length and simply traverses both lists to confirm if they are equal.

If you check two lists that are 1_000_000 and 1_000_001 in length then it is terribly inefficient.

So check the lengths first, then call `SequenceEqual` only if they are the same.

If you're checking for set equality rather than position equality then make a `HashSet<string>` out of each and then check against those.

Answer (score 1):

Your method of comparing the two lists is essentially this:

```
static bool SequenceUnorderedEqual<T>(
    IEnumerable<T> source1, IEnumerable<T> source2,
    IComparer<T> comparer = default)
{
    List<T> list1 = source1.ToList();
    List<T> list2 = source2.ToList();
    list1.Sort(comparer);
    list2.Sort(comparer);
    return list1.SequenceEqual(list2);
}
```

Using a dictionary is at least ten times faster, at the cost of being a bit more complex. It also doesn't require the items to be comparable (they only have to be equitable).

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

//...

/// <summary>
/// Determines whether two sequences are equal according to an equality comparer,
/// ignoring the order of the items in the sequences.
/// </summary>
static bool SequenceUnorderedEqual<T>(
    IEnumerable<T> source1, IEnumerable<T> source2,
    IEqualityComparer<T> comparer = default)
{
    Dictionary<T, int> occurences;
    if (Enumerable.TryGetNonEnumeratedCount(source1, out int count1) &&
        Enumerable.TryGetNonEnumeratedCount(source2, out int count2))
    {
        if (count1 != count2) return false;
        occurences = new(count1, comparer);
    }
    else
    {
        occurences = new(comparer);
    }

    // Populating the dictionary using source1.
    foreach (T item in source1)
    {
        CollectionsMarshal
            .GetValueRefOrAddDefault(occurences, item, out _)++;
    }

    // Depopulating the dictionary using source2.
    foreach (T item in source2)
    {
        ref int count = ref CollectionsMarshal
            .GetValueRefOrNullRef(occurences, item);
        if (Unsafe.IsNullRef(ref count) || count == 0) return false;
        count--;
    }

    // Now all counters should be zero.
    foreach (int count in occurences.Values) if (count != 0) return false;
    return true;
}
```

A simpler but less efficient implementation that doesn't take advantage of the [`CollectionsMarshal`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.collectionsmarshal) APIs, can be found in the [2nd revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/56598554/2) of this answer.

Comment: HOw to call this method , earlier we have used SequenceUnorderedEqual(Class class1, Class class2) but you have used SequenceUnorderedEqual<T>(Ienumberable<T> class1, IEnumerable<T> class2). Please help me out. how to call this IEnumerable type

Comment: @bmdprasad populate your two lists the way you are doing now, and then instead of sorting them and passing them to `SequenceEqual`, pass them unsorted to `SequenceUnorderedEqual`.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, using the `SequenceEqual` method from Linq will be very efficient. It effectively returns true if, quote, "the two source sequences are of equal length and their corresponding elements are equal according to the default equality comparer for their type", otherwise false. There won't really be a much faster way of doing this comparision.

Comment: Also, if your list is too long, you've posted another question in which an answer explains why that could impact performence. I advice you should refer to Sebastians comment above to check if this is the case.

Comment: as per your code it is comparing the data in the lists..So sequenceEqual will compares the data and count of lists as well ..Correct?

Comment: @bmdprasad - No, it does not check `Length` (which is bizarre).

Comment: @MaxDoesStuff - It does not check length.

Comment: I quoted the System.Linq documentation where it says the two lists must be of equal length - should I have put Count instead of Length?

Comment: @Enigmativity then why would `new int[] { 1, 2 }.SequenceEqual(new int[] { 1, 2, 1, 2 })` return false?

Comment: @MaxDoesStuff will it check data in both the lists

Comment: Yes, the code you posted in your original question will return false since the two lists are not the same

Comment: @MaxDoesStuff - The implementation of `SequenceEqual` does **not** check the length of the lists. It simply traverses both enumerables to confirm equal, and if it hits the end of one but not the other it will then return `false`.

Comment: can we write linq code I used var test = from l1 in list1 where list2.Any(x=>x == l1 select l1